# SQL query without UNION

Tags: sql

Can any one help me in rewriting the following query without using UNION statement?

```
(
  SELECT
    A.QRYNAME0 "Query Name",
    A.OPRID,
    A.DESCR,
    A.QRYTYPE,
    TO_CHAR(A.CREATEDTTM,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "Created On",
    TO_CHAR(A.LASTUPDDTTM,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "Last Updated On",
    B.EXECCOUNT "No of Times Executed",
    B.AVGEXECTIME,
    TO_CHAR(B.LASTEXECDTTM,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "Last Executed On"
    --TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(A.DESCRLONG,1,50))"Long Description"
  FROM
    PSQRYDEFN A,
    PSQRYSTATS B
  WHERE
    A.QRYNAME = B.QRYNAME and
    a.oprid = b.oprid
)
UNION
(
  SELECT
    A.QRYNAME "Query Name",
    A.OPRID,
    A.DESCR,
    A.QRYTYPE,
    TO_CHAR(A.CREATEDTTM,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "Created On",
    TO_CHAR(A.LASTUPDDTTM,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "Last Updated On",
    0 "No of Times Executed",
    0,
    NULL "Last Executed On"
    --TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(A.DESCRLONG,1,50)) "Long Description"
  FROM
    PSQRYDEFN A
  WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM   PSQRYSTATS B
      WHERE  a.qryname = b.qryname and a.oprid = b.oprid
    )
)
```

Comment: Only if you provide the DDL statements that where used to create the tables and if you describe the desired outcome of the query.

Comment: I think if you format it in a more readable manner and point out the difference you're more likely to get a reply.

Comment: tried reformatting. No idea whether it's better now, I don't write too much SQL by hand.

Comment: May I also suggest, that instead of PSQRYDEFN A, PSQRYSTATS B
, use something like PSQRYDEFN PQD, PSQRYSTATS PQS.  It goes a long way in making your statements readable and reusable.

Comment: This is a good example that shows that uppercasing your table- and column-names is a bad idea in terms of readability.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are simulating a left outer join. Try

```
A.QRYNAME *= B.QRYNAME and
a.oprid *= b.oprid
```

or even better, make it ANSI-compliant

```
FROM PSQRYDEFN A
LEFT OUTER JOIN PSQRYSTATS B ON A.QRYNAME=B.QRYNAME AND A.oprid=B.oprid
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for left outer join and isnull/nvl functions but without knowing the dialect of SQL and the tables cannot be exact

```
SELECT
    A.QRYNAME0 "Query Name",
    A.OPRID,
    A.DESCR,
    A.QRYTYPE,
    TO_CHAR(A.CREATEDTTM,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "Created On",
    TO_CHAR(A.LASTUPDDTTM,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "Last Updated On",
    nvl( B.EXECCOUNT, 0 ) "No of Times Executed",
    nvl( B.AVGEXECTIME, 0)
    nvl( TO_CHAR(B.LASTEXECDTTM,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), null) "Last Executed On"
    --TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(A.DESCRLONG,1,50))"Long Description"
FROM
    PSQRYDEFN A left outer join   PSQRYSTATS B
     on A.QRYNAME = B.QRYNAME and
         a.oprid = b.oprid
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,Please check the query and let me know that whether I can use it in this way

(SELECT DISTINCT A.QRYNAME   "Query Name" ,A.OPRID, A.DESCR ,  
A.QRYTYPE,TO_CHAR(A.CREATEDTTM,'DD-MON-YYYY 
HH24:MI:SS')"Created On",
TO_CHAR(A.LASTUPDDTTM,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')"Last 
Updated On",0 "No of Times Executed",0,
NULL "Last Executed On"
--TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(A.DESCRLONG,1,50)) "Long Description"
FROM PSQRYDEFN A, PSQRYSTATS B
WHERE A.QRYNAME = B.QRYNAME and a.oprid = b.oprid   OR  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1  FROM 
PSQRYSTATS B where
a.qryname = b.qryname  and a.oprid = b.oprid))

Comment: maybe, I would try it -. I am not being certain here as I find the outer join much easier to read than the or.

In the new query I think you will need to add some parentheses around the and ie where (.. and ...) or ....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need a LEFT OUTER JOIN of the two tables, plus you'll need to mangle the EXECCOUNT and EXECAVGTIME values with NVL to convert nulls to zeroes.